# Apache mod_rewrite weird behavior in Internet Explorer

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to setup redirection for a couple of root domains.

Firstly, here is the code in my **httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin ****@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example2.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192\.168\.0\.1$    # This is our WAN IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]

</VirtualHost>
```

What this does is redirect the root domain of **example.com** or **example2.com** or any host other than **www** to **www.example(2).com**

The part I'm having a problem with is the RewriteRule itself. the **$1** is supposed to match the pattern of the RewriteRule and add it in the substitution. For example: "**http://example.com/test.html**" should rewrite to "**http://www.example.com/test.html**"

It works in all modern browsers like it's supposed to except for IE8 or IE9 (I didn't test other IE versions).

In IE, this works:
"**http://example.com**" to "**http://www.example.com**"

In IE, this does not work:
"**http://example.com/test.html**" to "**http://www.example.com/test.html**"

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

I hope I've explained it well enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "does not work". mod_rewrite doesn't care what browser you use unless there's a RewriteCond on user agent or something.

Comment: I thought I clarified pretty well in the OP. Any modern browser other than IE this works: example.com/test.html to www.example.com/test.html but in IE that doesn't work. It will not rewrite the www part. However If I don't put anything after the slash then it does work, example: example.com to www.example.com works in every browser including IE. There is no user agent rewrite conditions. IE simply fails to follow the 301 redirect properly.

Comment: The `.htaccess` rules you've provided cannot cause IE to do something different than another browser. Something else is going on.

Comment: @ceejayoz: this is not a `.htaccess` but you're right: it can't be a browser problem unless morrty didn't give the whole rewrite rules.

Comment: @Olivier Pons: I assure you that the only thing I changed was our WAN IP address in the OP and the root domain to example.com, everything else is in its full. I guess I'll just deal with this behaviour. It's just weird that IE is the only browser doing this. I too doubt that anything I'm doing is affecting the browser but perhaps IE has always had this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try to ask to the Apache team/forums?

Comment: I did not, but I suppose I probably will now, thanks.

Comment: @morrty Please answer here... if you've found the solution, I'm interested.

Comment: @Olivier Pons It seems that Apache does not have official forums. I ended up not looking into it any further and writing it off as an IE is a terrible browser issue.

Comment: IE is a terrible browser issue... in general

Comment: did you try with and without the "NE" option (last rewriterule)?

Comment: How useful is `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$`? May I ask you to show me a method to get an `%{HTTP_HOST}` empty? I don't know how (no kidding).

Comment: I didn't try without NE, I can try that when I get back on Monday. As for your second question, I believe I found that line in the official documentation on the Apache website. I didn't understand it either, but I kept it in case it was some type of security risk.

Comment: I took out NE, as well as I commented out this line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$` with no success. Same behaviour displayed by IE. Also, here is the guide I used that shows that line you asked about: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: @OlivierPons Recently I was checking my error logs and noticed a hacking attempt: [error] [client [redacted]] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:) so it appears you can in fact hit the server without a hostname with some type of hacking tool. It appears that RewriteCond of an empty host is there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Placing this code in htaccess fixed a similar for me:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-8]" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Comment: Resolved my issue with IE 8!